# Toolbar/topbar missing on homepage only?

Tags: themes, homepage, admin-bar

My theme seems to have the `<?php wp_footer() ?>` and `<?php wp_head() ?>`, yet it's still not showing on the [homepage of my site](http://downtherabbithole.co.uk).

However, it is visible on all other pages and posts.

Comment: `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` are not responsible for showing your header. Even without them your header can be visible. They are hook to enqueue scripts or styles on header or footer. Please check your website in Chrome with Inspect Element or in FireFox with FireBug to identify why the header portion is not visible on the homepage but in the other pages. There can be either a CSS conflict or a js manipulation conflict - anything can be.

Comment: Now than, its not the header its only the toolbar which is not showing (http://premium.wpmudev.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/toolbar61.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mayeenul wrote: Use Firebug/Chrome Inspector to see what's wrong.

Look for Javascript Errors in the console see if the Adminbar is inside the DOM but hidden via CSS.

It could also be disabled via a filter in PHP with something like this:

```
if( is_front_page() ) {
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

... but I would say it's more likely that you have an error somewhere in the DOM or in your CSS/JS for the frontpage that is hiding the adminbar.

Comment: The only, thing showing in console is this `{"code":403,"headers":[{"name":"Content-Type","value":"application\/json"}],"body":{"error":"authorization_required","message":"An active access token must be used retrieve notifications."}}`

Comment: And is the admin bar present in the DOM? You can just check via `view sourcecode` if `<div id="wpadminbar"` is present.

Comment: Sorry was on wrong page, On the home page (where this adminbar is missing) firebug reports no errors. However the `id="wpadminbar"` is no where in the source http://pastebin.com/jjrxPUDX

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere in PHP. Do you have any caching plugins activated? Can you search in your sourcecode for the `show_admin_bar` filter?

Comment: No plugins but server side there is Cloudflare,APC and Varnish :( If it's caching shouldn't it still show in the source?

Comment: No, if it's caching it would totally make sense that it's missing on one page but showing on another. What classes does your <body>-Tag have? Is `logged-in` and `admin-bar` present?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry, I took a screenshot if that helps http://i.imgur.com/pcBwHiC.jpg

Comment: I can't move to this discussion to chat, as my rep is too low.

Comment: Yeah, too bad. :-(
Did you try pressing Ctrl + F5 to refresh the cache?

Comment: Yes I did try that but just the same, Could chat here if you have time http://us12.chatzy.com/51490556233678